# How I get the text of a select control

Tags: laravel

I am using a select control in my view , and I use the `id` to save it in a table, but i need too `id` `name` , to confirm this `id` and `name`. that in fact is a table (services)

I have used this two way of code that makes the same ... but I need get the `id` e `name` in diferent variables.

```
<select  ="serv" name="serv">
@foreach($serv as $id=>$name)
<option value="{{$id}}">{{$name}}</option>
@endforeach



{!! Form::select('serv',$serv,null,['id'=>'serv'])
```

Comment: Can you explain more. iam not able to understand your question.Do  you need id and name in post?

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
  {{ Form::select('serv',$serv->id,null,['id'=>'serv']) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! finally i used a script at onchange event , where i get the value and text of the select and then send this text to a hidden control.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowSelected()
{

var cod = document.getElementById("serv").value;



var combo = document.getElementById("serv");
var selected = combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text;


document.getElementById("serv2").value=selected;
}
</script>
```